# magento2 preference not working in Enterprise Edition 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, preference, magento-enterprise-2

magento2 while overriding class using preference, its not working in Enterprise Edition 2.3.5

In checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.crosssell">
            <action method='setCustomTemplate'>
            </action>
            <arguments>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
                <argument name="group_name" xsi:type="string">native</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.native" as="details.renderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Vendor_Module::checkout/cart/product/native.phtml" >
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">shoppingcart-native</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

In frontend/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\Cart\NativeBlock" />
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Please check updated question